# JS: Create comma separated values from values of multiple inputs

Tags: javascript, html

So I have this code

`myTask[]` is a select option like this

```
<select name="myTask[]" class="myTask" id="myTask1">
 <option value="1">Task1</option>
 <option value="2">Task1</option>
 <option value="3">Task1</option>
</select>


<select name="myTask[]" class="myTask" id="myTask2">
 <option value="1">Task1</option>
 <option value="2">Task2</option>
 <option value="3">Task3</option>
</select>

<select name="myTask[]" class="myTask" id="myTask3">
 <option value="1">Task1</option>
 <option value="2">Task2</option>
 <option value="3">Task3</option>
</select>
```

And easily get the values of these `select` using this code.

`JavaScript`

```
var task = document.getElementsByName('myTask[]');
for (var i = 0, iLen = task.length; i < iLen; i++) {
    alert(task[i].value);
}
```

But I want to store them in one `var` that is separated using commas.

If the user selects different `task` from different `select`

The value of  `var` should be something like this

`var arrTask = [2, 3, 1];`

I'm trying to store all selected values from 3 `select` into 1 `var`

Comment: Instead of `alert`, you could just push to an array: `taskArr.push(task[i].value)`, though you may want to convert that to a number or do some other operation beforehand.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `Array.from` to turn an array-like object (like the collection of `myTask[]` elements) into an array, while passing it through a mapper function to extract the `.value` of each select element:

```js
window.onchange = () => {
  const arrTask = Array.from(
    document.getElementsByName('myTask[]'),
    select => select.value
  );
  console.log(arrTask);
};
```

```html
<select name="myTask[]" class="myTask" id="myTask1">
 <option value="1">Task1</option>
 <option value="2">Task2</option>
 <option value="3">Task3</option>
</select>


<select name="myTask[]" class="myTask" id="myTask2">
 <option value="1">Task1</option>
 <option value="2">Task2</option>
 <option value="3">Task3</option>
</select>

<select name="myTask[]" class="myTask" id="myTask3">
 <option value="1">Task1</option>
 <option value="2">Task2</option>
 <option value="3">Task3</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Is the value going to be a string or number? You may need to `Number()` or `parseInt()`

Comment: I preferred string. Since my actual value for  option is something like this `option value="TXN1"`

Comment: Hello how can I define the select if I have multiple select options

Comment: What do you mean? The snippet *has* multiple select options already

Comment: For example I have 

myTask[] , myProj[], and myPos[]

Comment: If you want to select *all* selects on the page, use `document.querySelectorAll('select')`. If you want to select only those with certain names, use a query string: `document.querySelectorAll('[name="myTask[]"], [name="myProj[]"]')`, etc